# os.path.join with multiple files doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, path

I need some help with the following, I just can't seem to work this out.

I need to use `path.join` to build the path I want.

```
base_name = os.path.dirname(__file__)
input_file = apache.log
output_filename = os.path.join(base_name,"test_",input_file)
```

But I get `/Users/test/Dropbox/Python/apache.log` instead of  `/Users/test/Dropbox/Python/test_/apache.log` I don't understand why...

Thanks

Comment: I get ... `test_/apache.log`

Comment: Copy and paste your real code. You forgot to quote a string, that code doesn't execute. Who knows what other differences there are?

Comment: yeah I forgot to put quotes on the string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you just add the `test_` directory to the input_file var?

```
base_name = os.path.dirname(__file__)
input_file = "test_/apache.log"
output_filename = os.path.join(base_name, input_file)
```

Answer (score -1):

What about with:

```
base_name = os.path.dirname(__file__)
input_file = "apache.log"
output_filename = os.path.join(base_name,"test_",input_file)
```